# Combine css selectors with the same properties, php

Tags: php, css, parsing, minify

I'm looking for a PHP library(script) that will be able to combine CSS selectors with the same properties. Here is what I mean:

```
.myclass{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
.something{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
```

After processing the CSS above the result should be:

```
.myclass, .something{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is a good php parser https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser .with some research you could be able to do this .

Comment: does .something properties always equal to .myclass or they can be different, if they can be different which one should override?

Comment: is your CSS in separate file?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ , the idea here is to combine all selectors that have the same properties. If they have different prop. then should be left intact.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ , "is your CSS in separate file?" - take it as a string in php.

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? It is not going to magically prevent people from making redundant CSS declarations. If you are looking for better ways to manage/build CSS documents, perhaps you should be looking into SASS or LESS.

Comment: @MikeBrant , The CSS is already processed. How can SASS or LESS can help here? From what I've seen in docs, they can do this only using the "extend" feature.

Comment: @Smartik When you get into using tools like SASS or LESS, you find yourself writing more semantic CSS rules.  You manage them more like you would manage objects in an OOP language and have CSS artifacts generated from your definitions.  I guess I should have been clear in that I wasn't suggesting that you would need to use something like SASS or LESS to address this specific use case, but rather than going down the avenue of looking for some PHP-based solution to, at the end of the day, help you manage your CSS definitions, you might consider these tools specifically meant for this.

Comment: Even without SASS or LESS, I don't see why you would want to propagate this kind of bad CSS coding paradigm.  Why would you not just have a single CSS class called `font-red-14pt` or something semantically  meaningful like that rather than have two CSS class names that do the same exact thing? Right now you are looking for a "solution" to in essence remove a few lines of CSS when you might be better served to think differently about how you actually write the code to begin with.  Then you wouldn't need this "solution" at all.

Comment: @MikeBrant, yes, when possible I usually do create a single class, but here is not the case. As I said, here the code already exists and has to be optimized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice php library to do this is https://github.com/Cerdic/CSSTidy

Example code:

```
<?php
include('class.csstidy.php');

$css_code = '
.myclass{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
.something{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
';

$css = new csstidy();

$css->$css->set_cfg('merge_selectors', 2);

$css->parse($css_code);

echo $css->print->formatted();
?>
```

Output:

```
.myclass,.something {
  font-size:14px; color:red
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The code you've provided did not the trick, but I've edited your answer and now it works as expected. Once my edit will get approved, I'll accept the answer and apply the bounty rep points to you. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your edits have been rejected by three different reviewers (This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.), and I agree with the reasons of rejection. What is the main change that made the code work? `2` instead of `TRUE` as parameter in `set_cfg`? So that I can edit correctly my answer.

Comment: I've just improved the comment. Why would they reject it? That one was correct and similar to yours. Anyway, replace this line  `$css->set_cfg('merge_selectors', 2);`(instead of `remove_last_;`).

Comment: Done, I also updated the library link, removing the old one.

Comment: How to set logic there, example i want to get all selectors which color red.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

Feature: http://the-echoplex.net/csscrush/#core--inheritance

Library and Use: https://github.com/peteboere/css-crush